# $\vert G \vert < \infty$, $A,B,C \leq G$, $B \leq A \Rightarrow \vert A:B \vert \geq \vert C \cap A : C \cap B \vert$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am stuck with the following problem. I am sure it cannot be that hard since it is intuitively true, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Let $A,B,C \leq G$ where $G$ is a finite group. Suppose moreover that $B \leq A$. Then $\vert A:B \vert \geq \vert C \cap A : C \cap B \vert$.

Comment: it looks to me as a statement about integers. Have you tried to look at it that way?

Comment: @Weltschmerz: Not really but it looks worth it. On the other hand, I think Myself's answer is perfect. I had completely forgot the fact that $\vert A \vert \cdot \vert C \vert = \vert A \cap C \vert \cdot \vert AC \vert$. This proves instantly the implication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asked is to show that $\frac{|A|}{|B|} \geq \frac{|A\cap C|}{|C\cap B|}$ since everything is finite.

We may use that $|A|\cdot |C| = |A\cap C|\cdot |AC|$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$, this amounts to showing that $|AC| \geq |BC|$, which is obvious since $B\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need G to be finite.

You can construct the function $\begin{array}{rcl} f: (C\cap A)/ (C\cap B) & \to & A/B \\ x \cdot C\cap B & \to & x \cdot B \end{array}$

You can verify that f is well defined and injective and this gives you the desired inequality.